# Compiler won't let me use "DDSTextureLoader.h" and "WICTextureLoader.h"

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

I am trying to use the DirectXTex library but everytime I try, the compiler keeps giving me one error after another. More specifically, I want to use the headers `DDSTextureLoader.h` and `WICTextureLoader.h` so that I can use the functions `CreateWICTextureFromFile` and `CreateDDSTextureFromFile` so i can load textures onto my Direct3D11 application. But the compiler gives me 3 errors:

`Function 'DXGI_FORMAT MakeSRGB (DXGI_FORMAT)' already has a body`

`'=': unable to resolve function overload` this error repeats 2 times

`'SetDebugObjectName': ambiguous call to overloaded function` this error repeats 3 times

Compiler also says that these errors come from the file `WICTextureLoader.cpp`

I'm not sure what to do to fix these errors...Down below is my code
(I included all the header files that I used in my game)

```
#include <windows.h>    
#include <D3D11.h>                  
#include <dinput.h> 
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>            
#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>
#include <WICTextureLoader.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <SimpleMath.h>
#include <SpriteFont.h>
#include "DDSTextureLoader.cpp"
#include "WICTextureLoader.cpp"

CreateDDSTextureFromFile(device, L"SpaceSky512.dds", &SkyTexture, &SkyTextureResource);
CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, DevContext, L"grass.jpg", NULL, &Texture, 0);
```

I stopped using the headers from the legacy directX SDK and started using the windows SDK like most people. But how can i fix the compiler errors?

Answer (score 1):

These lines appear to be the source of your problem:

```
#include "DDSTextureLoader.cpp"
#include "WICTextureLoader.cpp"
```

You should only include header files in your source files, not other source files.  Instead you should link your application against the [DirectXTK library](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: The ``DDSTextureLoader.cpp`` and ``WICTextureLoader.cpp`` modules are already in the DirectXTK library. You can either use NuGet or project-to-project references to add DirectXTK to your project. See the DirectX Tool Kit [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK).